# Git changes lost on file save

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I recently updated my VS 2019 to v.16.11.5.

Now, every time I edit a file and save it, the git changes disappear, the changes counter reverts to 0 and in the solution explorer the icon next to the file goes to the blue lock (in sync).

Changes are saved locally but are lost as far as git is concerned and so they can't be committed, staged or pushed.

Same phenomenon when the git server is local or on github.com.

Can't reproduce this on other vs 2019 installations, the update works fine there.

I removed the github account, signed in again, repaired the whole VS installation, uninstalled antivirus/firewall, with no results.

Anyone else struggling with this?

Comment: I also reinstalled the github extension with no results.
What did it for my case was installing the latest [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) version.

Comment: The same thing happened to me on VS 16.11.23. Is there any fix for this issue? What to do if it happens next time? Thanks in advance.